# GeckoFX Contextmenu open link in new tab (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, browser, gecko, geckofx

I am programming a webbrowser based on GeckoFX 45 in Vb.Net and i could not get "Open link in new tab" to work. My question is: how can i get the link of the page right clicked as string to open it in a new tab?

the only way i could get it to work is `GeckoWebBrowser1.CopyLinkLocation` and read it from the clipboard but that is not the way i want to do this in a browser.

example:

[image: there is an example]

i hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

The property you are looking for is either:

```
var currentPageAddress = Browser.Document.Url
```

Bear in mind that if the page contains frames, you need to get the Url of the desired Frame element (`GetContentFrame()` is my logic to find a frame I need by name)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much vor your answer! Im a complete beginner in C# so i couldn´t implement that Code into my VB.NET Program and there is no `GeckoFrameElement`. Is there a way to use this in VB.NET?

Comment: I am 99.9% sure the same should be available in vb.net.